# Unit Testing with React.js, d3.js and mocha/chai

Tags: d3.js, mocha.js, reactjs, chai

I'm looking to do unit testing with react.js, d3 and mocha/chai. In order to integrate d3 with react.js, a lot of the d3 is done in componentDidMount since d3 cannot play very nicely with React's virtual DOM (similar to this http://nicolashery.com/integrating-d3js-visualizations-in-a-react-app/).

My question is how do I test the d3 functions? Is there a clean way I can wait for componentDidMount to complete before checking if the chart exists, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is using [React.renderComponent](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponent)'s callback.

```
React.renderComponent(Component(), node, onMountCallback);
```